# after installing panda while importing in python Error: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'

Tags: python, pandas, importerror

After installing panda while importing in python I got the following Error:

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)
  File "C:\Users\ss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "C:\Users\ss\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__config__.py", line 13, in <module>
    os.add_dll_directory(extra_dll_dir)
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'
```

Comment: seem like you didn't install the python correctly. try import os in your py file

Comment: Consider adding your code also so that one can find errors in that.

Comment: @JeffreyCheong maybe, ill reinstall python ill try it again.

Comment: @ShivamSuchak any solution?

Comment: Yes, maybe your python is not installed properly, or else globally same as mine, reinstall python then install pandas @GourabPaul

Answer (score 0):

Remove Numpy Package and install again. The error should go away.